# Space Complexity Recurrence

Tags: java, recursion, complexity-theory, space, recurrence

So this is a 2 part question.

I have some code that asks for the time complexity, and it consists of 3 for loops (nested):

```
public void use_space(int n)

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++)

//and at the end of the code, it makes a recursive call to the function
use_space(n/2);
use_space(n/2);
```

So what I derived for this time complexity recurrence was: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^3`. The reason I got that was because there were 2 recursive calls to the function each consisting of n/2 time and the nested for loops take n^3 time (3 loops).

IS this correct?

And then for the space complexity, I got `S(n) = S(n/2) + n`

Hope someone can clarify and tell me if this is wrong/explain. All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your timecomplexity is correct. You can use [masters theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to simplify it to `Theta(n^3)`

But your space complexity seems to be (a little) incorrect.
For every call of `use_space(n)` you have to save three numbers `i`, `j` and `k`. This numbers are at most of the size of `n` (if `n == N`, I think you mixed them up), so they need `log n` bits to be saved. Due to freeing the space after finishing `use_space` you only have to save one additional call `use_space(n/2)`.

So you get the space complexity `S(n) = S(n/2) + 3 log n`.

Improvement: You could free `i`, `j` and `k` after ending the three loops, so you do not need `3 log n` AND `S(n/2)` (at the same time), but first `3 log n` and after this `S(n/2)`, which will be frist `3 log (n/2)` and then `S(n/4)` (and so on), so you only need the maximum of the space used at the same time, which would be `3 log n`.